# VS2012 - XDesProc hangs when Xaml file is opened

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

In VS2012 whenever I try to open a xaml file (even in full XAML view) the XDesProc process keeps spinning and hangs visual studio. I tried killing it but it respawns.

I did some search online and found that people were complaining about this in the RC release. I am not using an RC release still I see this problem.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Once I deleted the process, it restarted, but VS2012U4 became responsive immediately and stayed responsive. I believe this problem relates to having 'ReSharper' enabled. I didn't have the problem again during the rest of the development session of six hours.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A lot of people are complaining about this (including my self).

Here is a work around for getting rid of the XDesProc and for speeding up XAML viewing performance: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/01/29/life-changer-xaml-tip-for-visual-studio.aspx

This will disable the designer in VS2012.

Comment: I noticed that even after using this approach, XDesProc spins in the background. So, my solution for now was to create a utility that kills XDesProc in the background.

Answer (score 1):

With my Visual Studio 2012.4, and 2gb of RAM used by XDeskProc, I resolve the problem by turning off the data loading in View Model’s constructor if in design mode. Loading the ItemsSources of my many Comboboxes just bogged down the designer

If DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject) Then
‘ Do nothing
Else
‘ Do something
End If

Answer (score 0):

The "Source Code (Text) Editor" doesn't work for me.

Apparently XDesProc still decides to come up with every character I type.
I have changed the permission of XDesProc such that "Everyone" is denied to read & execute to get it from starting at the first place.

Answer (score -3):

Translation:  Just found this fix that works for Visual Studio 2012

Original text: 
Solo encontre respuesta con este fix. Funciona para Visual 2012.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=36020