# How to design GUI for different monitor resolutions?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm designing and implementing the GUI for special application.

I'm using WPF on C#,

I intend to apply this app for different monitor resolutions (1366x768 or 1920x1080,...).

But I don't have any experience for this. I don't know how to implement the flexible GUI that can display on any resolution well.

Someone can give me the ideas?

Comment: Yes WPF is the best for those kind of things. You shouldn't set the Height and width of the columns exactly. Set it to Auto or *. Then maybe you need to go through basics of WPF.

Comment: @Richard Ev: I have thought about using percentage for size, or use Auto, * as Dilshod mentioned, but I want to get more idea before starting do it.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [WPF Layouts - A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start). If you use the appropriate layout controls, creating flexible GUI's is a breeze.

Answer (score 5):

1 - Write your XAML by hand and don't use the Visual Studio designer.

- The designer produces fixed-size fixed-position UIs (ala winforms) and will not be useful if you need resolution independence.

2 - Do not fix the sizes and positions of the UI elements yourself either.

- Don't do things such as `<TextBox Width="56" Margin="50,30,10,5"/>`. Instead of that, place your UI inside resolution independent layout containers such as [`Grid`](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) or `DockPanel`. Use Star Sizes in your Grids, too.

**Edit:** Adding @Viv's comment, which is so important I decided to make it part of the answer:

Like everything else in programming, take point 1 with a grain of salt. Don't make it another statement like *"In MVVM ANY code in code-behind is wrong"*. Using the Designer(VS/Blend) for things like generating Template's, Modifying Storyboards, VSM, Importing Illustrator/Photoshop files is perfectly reasonable. Know what you're dealing with and even if in such cases you get constant dimensions, tweak the xaml accordingly to get rid of it than totally neglect every aspect of it

Comment: It is great!
Thank you, HighCore!

Comment: Writing XAML by hand has a lot of benefits, particularly in VS2012 where [the XAML designer (XDesProc) locks up periodically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653835/vs2012-xdesproc-hangs-when-xaml-file-is-opened/14483094#comment23129670_14483094).  It seems like a step backward at first (drag and drop UI development was a big advancement when it came out), but it's oddly easier and more productive than WinForms even once you get used to XAML.

Comment: @DanBryant Every UI designer that I've ever used has been something that shouldn't be relied on entirely, whether it be WPF, winforms, ASP, plain HTML (with your choice of editors), Java swing apps, etc.  They can be useful in occasional instances to do a bit of work, but can virtually never be relied on entirely.  The inherent complexity of UI design is just too complex for designers in general.

Comment: Like everything else in programming, take point 1 with a grain of salt. Don't make it another statement like "In MVVM **ANY** code in code-behind is wrong". Using the Designer(VS/Blend) for things like generating Template's, Modifying Storyboards, VSM, Importing Illudtrator/Photoshop files is perfectly reasonable. Know what you're dealing with and even if in such cases you get constant dimensions, tweak the xaml accordingly to get rid of it than totally neglect every aspect of it.

Comment: @Viv Most reasonable and wise comment EVER. I'm editing my answer and adding it verbatim.

Comment: @Viv I suppose the more accurate statement would be, "Don't rely entirely on designer-generated code".  This can mean either writing it from scratch, or making *significant* changes to the designer generated code to account for its weaknesses.

Comment: @Servy, fair enough; perhaps I'm just a bit bitter from running into so many designer issues in the past year or so that have impaired productivity.  I'm still hopeful that we'll eventually have more intelligent visual designers.  The XAML designer is actually pretty smart, given the complexity of the problem it's trying to solve, and I shouldn't dismiss the work of the talented engineers who've developed it.  It's frustrating because it _almost_ works for what I want it to do, but there are enough issues that I've had to disable it entirely for now.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it depends somewhat on the nature of the application, however the resolutions you specify are not MASSIVELY different in the grand scheme of things (if you were comparing 640x480 to 2560x1600, then you might have even bigger concerns!), so likely, if you choose the right components, they will organise themselves (or more aptly, the OS will organise them behind the scenes) for you.

The fact that you've chosen WPF means that you have massive flexibility with how UI elements will render, as WPF is natively a vector based rendering engine, as opposed to Windows Forms (GDI/GDI+) which was a DPI/per-pixel based rendering engine.

But lets delve a little deeper into this shall we?

Say for example you were designing your UI in Windows Forms, and it required a ToolStrip on the form, and then you all 1000 buttons to the ToolStrip. Okay, on a massive monitor, you might just see all 1000 buttons, but on your bog standard 1080p monitor, you might only see 30 of them; so what happens to the rest? - Windows will put these in a sub-menu for you, at the end of the ToolStrip, so that you can still access them, even though they are not on the main (visible) section of the ToolStrip. I'm pretty sure that the same principle will apply to WPF, through you will likely have even greater control over how things render, and appear!

The great thing that WPF brought to the table, through vector rendering, was resolution independence. This gives you the flexibility to decide if you want your elements to render as a "fixed" size (across any resolution, it will always use the same pixels), or, allow the engine to dynamically resize the element according to the resolution (on a low resolution the element will render using less pixels but will suffer with lesser quality, or on a high resolution, will render using more pixels and will have a much higher quality).

To get you started, here's a free WPF eBook from SyncFusion (seriously, check them out, they give away quite a bit of free, decent stuff!)

[WPF Succinctly](http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/wpf)